# I am trying to get items in my dialog box selectable and on selection run more ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dialog

I have a button form search that on click it does some ajax and I am appending that data to a dialog box. I am wanting to make those elements selectable and on selection open another dialog box that drilled into more detail. I am using jquery any help would be appreciated.

html

```
<div class="row">
 &nbsp; <button onclick="return Search_All_Forms()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Search Forms</button>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Search Forms">

</div>
```

javascript

```
function Search_All_Forms() {
  //if (getCookieValue('PAYREG') != '99') {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: baseAzureServiceUrl + "/api/dynamicforms/FormHeader/search",
    //data: { add_userid: getCookieValue('USERID'), empl_id: getCookieValue('EMPLID'), location: getCookieValue('LOCATION'), status: 'STARTED' },
    data: {
      add_userid: 'UJCOCKR'
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, elements) {
        var strTitle = elements.form_title;
        var intFormDatatHeaderID = elements.form_data_header_id;
        // alert(intFormDatatHeaderID);
        var html = '';
        html += '<ul id="selectable">';
        html += '<li>' + strTitle + '</li>';
        html += '</ul>';
        $("#dialog").dialog({
          autoopen: false,
          modal: true,
          draggable: true,
          position: [200, 150],
          dialogClass: "foo",
          show: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 1000
          }
        });
        $(".ui-corner-all").css("background-color", "white");
        //$("#dialog").append(strTitle + "<br>");
        $("#dialog").dialog("open")
        $('#dialog').append(html)
        $('#selectable').selectable();
        //alert(data); 
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Getting any errors in the console?

Comment: no sir I am not I actually get my first dialog with a list of the items I want I just do not know how to make them selectable. This is like a drill down they select a button shows first dialog they select out of that dialog then another shows they select out of that one and they get their final result.

Comment: First off, if you have more than one selectable object returned you should use a class instead of an ID (as in class='selectable' instead of id='selectable') IDs are supposed to be unique to one element on the page. This would also change the selectable function call to $('.selectable').selectable();

Comment: thank you I will try something like that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your exact problem but when you append elements to the document you can use `event delegation` to attach event handlers to those elements. Like so:

```
$(document)
     .on("click","#selectable li", function(e){
           $("#dialog").dialog.("open");
     });
```

And the dialog option for auto open is spelled `autoOpen` not `autoopen`.
Also:

```
 $("#dialog").dialog("open"); //<-- wrong order i thing
 $('#dialog').append(html);
```

---

Should be:

```
 $('#dialog').append(html);
 $("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

Let me know if you're any closer to solving the problem

Comment: And of course generating the elements with `.class` instead of `#id`. Forgot about that :P

Answer (score 0):

After your dialog() call, you can use something like this to have the new .selectable elements produce a dialog of their own when clicked:

```
$('.selectable').selectable({
    selected:function(e, ui){
        var eleText = $(ui.selected).text();
        var addText = "";
        switch(eleText){
            case "Test":
                addText = "Here's a brief description of the selected Test element.";
                break;
            case "E2":
                addText = "Here's some more information on the E2 element.";
                break;
        }
        $('<div>').text(addText).dialog();
    }
});
```

Of course, instead of using the switch statement, you could pass the element text (or ID if you use them) to a server via ajax, and use information from the response as the description in the new dialog box - but that's really only if you don't want the information to be sitting on the client's PC to begin with (like if there was a ton of text or images that would slow down the initial call to the page).